# FTDI Change PID to default

Tags: pid, ftdi

I tried to change PID in the FTDI chip (R232R) through FT_Prog. It was working but after it I found that Windows 7 automaticaly reinstal the drivers for USB device, not FTDI device. So I want to change back PID to default (6001). The problem is that I can not see this device in FT_Prog app because it has different PID number. I also tried MProg but with same result. I also tried reinstal Windows FTDI drivers manualy, but still can not see FTD device in FT_Prog. 
I actualy do not get it why is possible to change PID, if you cut of the communication with FT_Prod.

Answer (score 4):

Ok, finally I foud a solution. Thanks to Preston. I just make a copy of default Windows FTDI drivers, open FTDIBUS.inf change PID number from default 6001 to my 6005 and just make manual instalation of driver. It is working now and also I can connect to my FTDI chip with standard FTDI tool FT_Prog. So with this I can simply create my own drivers just with my combination of VID and PID. More information in technical note from FTDI TN_104.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you programmed your PID but you have no driver to match that PID. So your device will enumerate, but it's not going to associate with any USB driver on the system.

You can modify the original driver to add in your PID, and then install that driver for your modified device.

Alternatively you can force the load of the original driver on the device. Open Device Manager then right click on your device and select Update Driver. Then click Browse, then click Let Me Pick. Finally click Have Disk then browse to your original driver. It will prompt you that it doesn't match and ask if you are sure - you can say yes to force the load of the original driver. This will give you access to change your PID back to what it was before.